# Using negative lookahead to exclude strings with condition but not ones longer than certain number of characters

Tags: regex, string

I have this find regex:

```
^(?=.{35})(?!.*(?:-\h)).{0,35}[\h.]
```

It matches every line until the last whitespace/dot before the 35th position of the line, it also excludes lines starting with a dash.

Now I want to **include** lines starting with a dash and longer than 35 characters.

I tried with:

```
^(?=.{35})(?!.*(?:-\h.{0,35})).{0,35}[\h.]
```

But it doesn't work as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Example text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
- Include this line Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
- This line is too short.
```

Thanks

Comment: If you have 75 chars in the line and the last two chars are `-\t` the regex will fail, even though you seem to be focused on a max of 35 characters. This `^(?=.{35})(?!.*(?:-\h))` causes that.

Answer (score 1):

Matching at least 35 chars after the `-` can be done using `^-.{35,}` If you want to match both, you could use an alternation `|` matching either of the alternatives:

```
^(?:(?=.{35})(?!.*(?:-\h)).{0,35}[\h.]|-.{35,})
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XMO5nL/1)